# How do I install linux "header" files for virtual machines?

Tags: debian, software-installation, virtualbox, dependencies

I installed virtualbox on my desktop running Debian 9 and I downloaded a virtual machine file that I imported into virtualbox. The problem is when I try to start the VM it tells me to run '/sbin/vboxconfig' in the terminal so I did and I got this:

```
root@MaxPC:/home/maxwell# /sbin/vboxconfig
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxdrv.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxdrv.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxballoonctrl-service.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxballoonctrl-service.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxautostart-service.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxautostart-service.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxweb-service.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxweb-service.service.
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
    linux-headers-amd64 linux-headers-4.18.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
    linux-headers-amd64 linux-headers-4.18.0-0.bpo.1-amd64

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
```

I then ran 'sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.18.0-0.bpo.1-amd64' to see if that would fix it but I got this:

```
root@MaxPC:/home/maxwell# sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.18.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-4.18.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 : Depends: linux-compiler-gcc-6-x86 (>= 4.14.17-1~) but 4.9.130-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What the heck do I do to get my VMs to start?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://askubuntu.com/q/75709/612676

Comment: Ubuntu provides a `virtualbox-dkms` package that does it all, assuming you install VB using the Ubuntu repos.  Checking the dependencies on it it only requires `dkms >=2.1.0.0` so you may be able to manually download and install it

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in [this bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=895819) you need to specify a target release.  Try:

```
sudo apt-get install -t stretch-backports linux-headers-4.18.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
```